# JOGL procedural textures are blobbed when scaled

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I'm currently having issues in my JOGL app where the textures I'm creating appear as blobs when scaled. The IDE is Netbeans 6.9.1.

I'll explain my texture creation process in detail.

First I'm doing:

```
    gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);

    BufferedImage buff = ByteBuffer_To_BufferedImage(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
    _list_of_textures[count] = TextureIO.newTexture(buff, true);
```

...where "data" is a byte array.

My method "ByteBuffer_To_BufferedImage()" does the following:

```
int p = _width* _height* 4;
  int q; // Index into ByteBuffer
  int i = 0; // Index into target int[]
  int w3 = _width* 4; // Number of bytes in each row
  for (int row = 0; row < _width; row++) {
p -= w3;
q = p;
for (int col = 0; col < _width; col++) {
  int iR = data.get(q++)*2;     //127*2 ~ 256.
  int iG = data.get(q++)*2;     
  int iB = data.get(q++)*2;     
  int iA = data.get(q++)*2;
  pixelInts[i++] =
    ((iA & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
        ((iR & 0x000000FF) << 16) |
    ((iG & 0x000000FF) << 8) |
         (iB & 0x000000FF);
}
  }

  // Create a new BufferedImage from the pixeldata.
  BufferedImage bufferedImage =
new BufferedImage( _width, _height,
           BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  bufferedImage.setRGB( 0, 0, _width, _height,
            pixelInts, 0, _width);
    return bufferedImage;
```

...which basically orders the bytes for an RGBA color scheme.

When I draw, I do it like so...

```
    _textures[c].enable();
    _textures[c].bind();
    gl.glTexEnvi(GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_MODULATE);
    TextureCoords coords = _textures[c].getImageTexCoords();

    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);

    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.left(), coords.top());
    gl.glVertex3f(...);  // Top Left

    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.right(), coords.top());
    gl.glVertex3f(...);   // Top Right

    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.right(), coords.bottom());
     gl.glVertex3f(...);  // Bottom Right

    gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.left(), coords.bottom());
    gl.glVertex3f(...); // Bottom Left

    gl.glEnd();
    _textures[c].disable();
```

And that's about it. I know of some options you can set with javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities, but I'm not sure if it would help.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or know of it's cause? Also, if anyone can suggest an alternate means of texture creation given my byte array I'll try that out also.

**Edit:**

I went back and tried creating the textures using "java-less" OpenGL.

```
    gl.glGenTextures(1,  _textures,layer);
    gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[count]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexImage2D(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.GL_RGBA,
            _width, _height, 0,
            GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
```

This yields the same results (pixels are blobs instead of rectangles).

**Edit:**

The last post I made lead me to question the bilinear filtering being done. This indeed turned out to be the problem.

If you need to maintain exact pixel values you need to use `GL_NEAREST` (no filtering/interpolating at all). I've run into this problem before and actually feel pretty dumb for not remembering the solution sooner.

Comment: What does correct output look like?

Comment: Here's a link to correct output: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/specklefix.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried GL_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR?

Comment: Yes you figured it out just as I did lol. Thank you for the response!